# Old spawned players cannot update position of new spawned players, but new spawned players can track updated positions of old spawned players

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, networking, socket.io

I have the following weird situation occuring, whenever a player spawns, the previous players can receive the spawn event from the server and are able to spawn the new player, but they are not able to update the new player position.

The weird part is that new players are able to track the positions of old players, but old players are not able to track the update position of new players.

I've been debbugging and i noticed that the dictonary of type <string, NetworkIdentity> where i save the "serverObjects" (players) in the old player client it doesn't save the new players, but they can spawn the new players. Because of this i believe that i'm not able to update other new players position. Even though i do not know clearly what i'm doing wrong...

This is the NetworkClient.cs (unity)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using SocketIO;
using System;

public class NetworkClient : SocketIOComponent
{

    [Header("Network Client")]
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform networkContainer;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject playerPrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private Dictionary<string, NetworkIdentity> serverObjects;

    public static string ClientID {get; private set;}

    


    public override void Start() {
        base.Start();
        initialize();
        SetupEvents();  
    }

    private void initialize(){
        serverObjects = new Dictionary<string, NetworkIdentity>();
    }

    public override void Update() {
        base.Update();
        On("close", (e) => {
            Debug.Log("Se ha desconectado del servidor");
        });
    }

    private Vector3 decryptPos(string pos){
        var positions = new string[3];
        positions = pos.Split(':'); 
        //Debug.Log("Soy el possss");
        Debug.Log(pos);

        float x = float.Parse(positions[0]) ;
        float y = float.Parse(positions[1]) ;
        float z = float.Parse(positions[2]) ;

        Vector3 pos3d = new Vector3(x,y,z);
        return pos3d;
    }

    private void SetupEvents() {
        On("open", (e) => {
            Debug.Log("Conexión realizada con el servidor");
        });

        On("register", (e) => {
            ClientID = e.data["id"].ToString();
            //Debug.LogFormat("Nuestro Cliente tiene ID ({0})", ClientID);
        });

        On("spawn", (e) => {

            string id = e.data["id"].ToString();
            GameObject go = Instantiate(playerPrefab, networkContainer);
            NetworkIdentity ni = go.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();


            if(ClientID != id){
                //En el caso de que está recibiendo el spawn de otro player

                var debug = string.Format("Otro Player ({0})", id);
                //Debug.Log(debug);
               // Debug.Log(e);

                //Debug.Log("Está spawneando otro player!!");

                
                go.name = string.Format("Other Player ({0})", id);
                

                //Getting and setting the position of the other player
                string pos = e.data["encodedPosition"].str;
                Vector3 position = decryptPos(pos);
                go.transform.position = position;
                
                ni.SetControllerID(id);
                ni.SetSocketReference(this);
                serverObjects.Add(id,ni);

                
            } else {

                //Debug.Log("Estoy espawneando :OO");
                go.name = string.Format("Player ({0})", id);

                ni.SetControllerID(id);
                ni.SetSocketReference(this);
                serverObjects.Add(id, ni);

            }

            ni = null;

            
        });

        On("updatePosition", (e) => {
            string id = e.data["id"].ToString();

            Debug.Log("SOY EL DATA QUE VIENE DEL SERVER");
            //Debug.Log(e.data["encodedPosition"]);

            var pos = e.data["encodedPosition"].str;
            var positions = new string[3];
            positions = pos.Split(':'); 

            ///Debug.Log("Soy el possss");
            //Debug.Log(positions[0] +"|||"+positions[1]+"|||"+positions[2]);

            float x = float.Parse(positions[0]) ;
            float y = float.Parse(positions[1]) ;
            float z = float.Parse(positions[2]) ;

            //Debug.Log("Soy el possss22222");
            //Debug.Log(x +"|-|-|"+y+"|-|-|"+z);

            foreach (var item in serverObjects)
            {
                Debug.Log(item);
            }

            if(!serverObjects[id]){

            } else {
                NetworkIdentity ni = serverObjects[id];


            }

            Debug.LogFormat("Server Object: {0}", serverObjects[id]);

            Vector3 posi = new Vector3(x,y,z);
            ni.transform.position = posi;

            Debug.Log("Soy el ultimate position...");
            Debug.Log(posi);

        });

        On("disconnected", (e) => {
            string id = e.data["id"].ToString();
            GameObject go = serverObjects[id].gameObject;
            Destroy(go); //Removiendo al jugador de la partida
            serverObjects.Remove(id); // Removiendolo de memoria
        });
        
    }
}
```

This is the NetworkIdentity.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using SocketIO;

public class NetworkIdentity : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Helpful Values")]
    [SerializeField]
    [GreyOut]
    private string id;
    [SerializeField]
    [GreyOut]
    private bool isControlling;

    private SocketIOComponent socket;

    void Awake()
    {
        isControlling = false;
    }

    public void SetControllerID (string ID){
        id = ID;
        isControlling = (NetworkClient.ClientID == ID) ? true: false; //Verifica si la id que viene pertenece al player o es de otro (para definir quien controla el personaje)
    }

    public void SetSocketReference(SocketIOComponent Socket){
        socket = Socket;
    }

    public string GetID(){
        return id;
    }
    
    public bool IsControlling(){
        return isControlling;
    }

    public SocketIOComponent GetSocket(){
        return socket;
    }
}
```

This is the NetworkTransform.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NetworkIdentity))]
public class NetworkTransform : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    [GreyOut]
    private Vector3 oldPosition;

    private NetworkIdentity networkIdentity;
    private Player player;

    private float stillCounter = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
       networkIdentity = GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();
       oldPosition = transform.position;
       player = new Player(); 
       player.position = new Position();
       player.position.x = 0;
       player.position.y = 0;
       player.position.z = 0;
       player.id = networkIdentity.GetID().Trim( new Char[] { '"' } );

       if(!networkIdentity.IsControlling()){
           //enabled = false; //Turn off the script if not own player
       }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(networkIdentity.IsControlling()){
            if(oldPosition != transform.position){
                oldPosition = transform.position;
                stillCounter = 0f;
                sendData();
            } else {
                stillCounter += Time.deltaTime;
                if(stillCounter >= 1f){
                    stillCounter = 0f;
                    sendData();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void sendData(){
        //Actualiza la información del player y la manda al server
        player.position.x = (float)Math.Round(transform.position.x,3);
        player.position.y = (float)Math.Round(transform.position.y,3);
        player.position.z = (float)Math.Round(transform.position.z,3);

        player.encodePosition();
        var encodedJSONPos = player.toJSON();

        //Debug.Log("Soy la posicion del playersino: ");
        //Debug.Log(encodedJSONPos);

        networkIdentity.GetSocket().Emit("updatePosition", encodedJSONPos );
    }
 }
```

This is the Player.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public string username;
    public string id;
    public Position position;
    public EncodedPlayerMovement encodedPlayerMovement = null;

    public void encodePosition (){
            
            this.encodedPlayerMovement = new EncodedPlayerMovement();

            //Saving the id
            this.encodedPlayerMovement.id = this.id;

            //Saving the encoded position

            //var debug = string.Format("Soy la posicion antes de ser codificada: x: ({0}) y: ({1}) z: ({2}) ", position.x, position.y, position.z);
            //Debug.Log(debug);

            var encodedPos = position.x+":"+position.y+":"+position.z;
            encodedPos = encodedPos.Replace(",",".");
            this.encodedPlayerMovement.encodedPosition = encodedPos;

            //Debug.Log("Soy la posicion despues de ser codificada");
            //Debug.Log(encodedPos);
    }
        
 
    
    public JSONObject toJSON() {
        var jsonPlayer = this;
        //return  new JSONObject(JsonUtility.ToJson(this));
        return  new JSONObject(JsonUtility.ToJson(this.encodedPlayerMovement));
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class EncodedPlayerMovement {
    public string id;
    public string encodedPosition;
}
```

This is the PlayerManager.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Data")]
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 4f;

    [Header("Class Reerences")]
    [SerializeField]
    private NetworkIdentity networkIdentity;

    void Update()
    {
        if(networkIdentity.IsControlling()){
            checkMovement();
        }
    }

    private void checkMovement(){
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        transform.position += new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

And this is the index.js of the server code in nodejs

```
var io = require('socket.io')(process.env.PORT || 52300);

//Custom classes
var Player = require('./classes/Player');


console.log('Server has started');
var players = [];
var sockets = [];

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Conexión realizada!');


    var player = new Player();
    var thisPlayerID = player.id;

    players[thisPlayerID] = player;
    sockets[thisPlayerID] = socket;


    socket.emit('register', {id: thisPlayerID}); //Avisarle al cliente cual es su id en el servidor mediante un objeto json (no es necesario json.stringify pues se hace automatico)
    socket.emit('spawn', player) //Avisa al player actual que ha spawneado
    socket.broadcast.emit('spawn', player) //Avisa a los demas que el player actual ha spawneado (avisa a todos menos al player actual)


    //Avisar al player actual sobre todos los demas players conectados en el servidor (no se avisa sobre si mismo)
    for(var playerID in players) {
        if(playerID !== thisPlayerID){
            socket.emit('spawn', players[playerID]);
        }
    }


    //Evento de positional data from player
    socket.on('updatePosition', (data) => {
        console.log("soy el data");
        console.log(data);

        var deserializePos = data.encodedPosition;//.encodedPosition;
        var position = deserializePos.split(':');

        console.log("ANTES DE TODO: Estoy recibiendo los cambios de posición del player... El player debe emitirse a los demas jugadores...");
        console.log(position)

        var x = parseFloat(position[0]);
        var y = parseFloat(position[1]);
        var z = parseFloat(position[2]);

        console.log("ANTES DE ENCODE: Estoy recibiendo los cambios de posición del player... El player debe emitirse a los demas jugadores...");
        console.log(x,y,z)

        player.position.x = x;
        player.position.y = y;
        player.position.z = z;

        player.EncodePosition();
        console.log("DESPUES DE ENCODE: Estoy recibiendo los cambios de posición del player... El player debe emitirse a los demas jugadores...");
        console.log(player)
        //Avisarle a los demas que el player actual ha cambiado su posicion (se envia objeto player con la data)
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatePosition', player);
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("Un jugador se ha desconectado...");
        delete players[thisPlayerID];
        delete sockets[thisPlayerID];
        socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected', player);
    });

});
```

Finally here is an image of what it looks like my scene...
[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1MX8.png)

What should i do in order to prevent this bug?

Comment: I think this needs a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe a repo  with the project could work?

Comment: No, I think you should read the link.  The problem is that this is an enormous amount of code and, given that people here are helping you for free, you will be much more likely to attract answers if you put in the effort to narrow down the problem to a more digestible size of code.  Very few people will invest the effort to read through and troubleshoot this much code because it takes an enormous amount of time.  The purpose of StackOverflow is not to find help for your problem, but to build a library of questions with lasting value for future readers.  This question does not do that.

Comment: Thanks J... i will do my best to narrow the problem by following the link instructions, thanks for your guide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

As i thought it was a client-side problem in the "spawn" event inside NetworkClient.cs, thing is that the setting of the network identity inside of the if (ClientID != id) was buggy, not sure why but when i moved the pieces of code above the if statement the array of dictionary<string,networkIdentity> began to work.

This was tricky, but the process of solving the problem was key so i will describe how i did it for people that don't know well where to begin or how to ask for help as happened to me...

Steps:

1. Open multiple unity editor in order to view console logs of different clients. This can be achieved by this little hack: Clone the unity project inside the projects folder, rename it, erase the Assets folder inside the cloned project and then make a hard link with mklink in bash in order to redirect the assets folder of the original project into the cloned projects, this will allow to maintain updated every cloned project with the original project and avoid multiple code editions in order to properly debug the new changes. If you do not know how to make hard links just google it, it is really straightforward.
2. Make public any variable, struct, list or gameobject that you want to debug. Sometimes "Debug.Log" is not enough to know what is happening on runtime. In my case i was using a Dictionary to save serverObjects and Dictionaries can't be showed in the unity editor when you make it public so i have to make first a struct that was similar to the dictionary and then make a list of type struct, then you can make it public and see in the unity editor what is happening more clearly.
3. Debug, Change, Debug. Sometimes you will have to try different things but always you will find and for each debug cycle you will get a more clear understanding of what the problem is.

This was my process to solve this tricky problem and surely will work for debug your tricky network problem too!